# what is wrong with object constructor doing more than assigning its dependencies?

Tags: oop, dependency-injection, language-agnostic, coding-style

I came across some text dictating good practices "***Do nothing inside a constructor, only assign properties..***" followed by below before and after refactored code. Truly speaking, I have been following this practice but would like to know and understand some better examples where things can go wrong if this guideline not obeyed.

**Before Refactoring :**

```
final class MySQLTableGateway
{
    private Connection connection;
    public function __construct(
        ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration,
        string tableName
    ) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.connect(connectionConfiguration);
    }
    private function connect(
        ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration
    ): void {
        this.connection = new Connection(
            // ...
        );
    }
    public function insert(array data): void
    {
        this.connection.insert(this.tableName, data);
    }
}
```

**Refactored Version**

```
final class MySQLTableGateway
{
    private ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration;  
    public function __construct(
        ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration,
        string tableName
    ) {
        this.connectionConfiguration = connectionConfiguration;
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }
    private function connect(
        ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration
    ): void {
        if (this.connection instanceof Connection) {
            return;                                             
        }
        this.connection = new Connection(
            // ...
        );
    }
    public function insert(array data): void
    {
        this.connect();                                       
        this.connection.insert(this.tableName, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you read this guideline from? Did they not explain the reasoning for it?

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ no, they didn't explained - hence the question.

Comment: So, basically they have made an unsubstantiated claim :-) Regardless, the reason *I* avoid doing too much in the constructor is to get my object into a stable state as quickly as possible and without the risk of an exception occurring. If your constructor is just one in a long chain of construction, an exception can complicate matters. So, the guideline is to create your object as quickly as possible and with as little risk of exception occurring.